Malware in browser on Ubuntu?
By mistake I opened a link in a spam email and, even though the browser (Vivaldi) blocked the page from loading, I wanted to understand if there may have been a malware download or something else.
There is a way to check if my browser is infected with malware?

You've provided few specifics; no mention of what Ubuntu product/release you're using, nor how the browsers are packaged. One benefit of a snap contained browser is added security; ie. the browser runs in a container with limited access to your root file-system, so specifics matter. Google Chrome is not snap packaged for one (has access to your root file-system).

You are right, sorry.
My browser is Vivaldi 6.7.3329.29 (stable channel) stable (64 bit)
I don't think it's a snap.

To make sure that Vivaldi web browser isn't infected with malware run the following commands to uninstall and reinstall it.
cd ~/Downloads/
sudo apt-get --purge remove vivaldi-stable
wget -c https://downloads.vivaldi.com/stable/vivaldi-stable_6.7.3329.27-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./vivaldi-stable_6.7.3329.27-1_amd64.deb


A thousand thanks,
I proceed to be safe.
I would like to ask you just one question out of pure curiosity: since the incident happened to today I have received two Vivaldi updates, can the browser be updated despite the infection?

I don't think so, although modern  web browsers typically download the entire new version of the browser when updating. To be on the safe side I'd go with completely reinstalling Vivaldi rather than trying to update it from its existing installation.
